# Shrinkwrap stretches, distorts the object when applied

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, shrinkwrap

The look that I am trying to achieve is to have the hexagonal shapes on top of the base mesh. But the hexagonal shapes are getting stretched and distorted. I do not want the Hexagonal shapes to change shape, but just bend along the base mesh.

I have tried the Curve modified but it also changes the shape.
Even tried the Lattice modifier to match the base shape as well as I can but still there is slight stretching which I do not want.

Is there a better way to go about doing this?
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image: Shrinkwrap modifier, stretching]

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible with modifiers. Even the cast modifier using a shere doesn't succeed in keeping the ratio between the cells. The difference between the flat surface and the egg is too big. You can try baking the cells as a normal map and counter distortions with a tweak in the UV unwrap.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
The base mesh will be deleted later and only the hexagonal shapes will remain. Baking the normal map and achieving the same with UV unwrap is not an option for this project.
Any other work around or software that might help with this?